# Turn divs into page anchor for cycle all slideshow

Tags: jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm building a slideshow with cycle-all plugin and I want the page anchors to be div's elsewhere on the page.

How do I make the .pager divs correspond to the .section-testimonials slides?

here is the markup and jquery:

```
<div id="slide-nav">
<div class="pager">
    <div>
        stuff in here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pager">
    <div>
        stuff in here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pager">
    <div>
        stuff in here
    </div>
</div>
</div>

$('.section-testimonials').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 1000,
    containerResize: 0,
    timeout: 9000,
    pager:      '#slide-nav',
    pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
    pauseOnPagerHover: true,
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
    // return sel string for existing anchor
    return '#slide-nav .pager:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried selecting different div's but no cigar

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
See this example:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/goto.html